# Renewal Status & Process

Tags: civimember

we might have got our sequence / settings wrong, I'm not certain.

Currently  ( and likely in teh future ) we collect membership subs manually, with an annual membership.

We set it up such that memberships expire ( 1 Jan ) and when they expire they go into grace instantly for 2 years.

Then we manually collect sub in the spring and then batch load these based.

The membership contributions get recorded, but the status remains 'grace'.

Have we got this wrong? Should the membership be let expire not go to grace? Logically I guess the sequence should be member - end of year it becomes pending payment and only if payment not received it goes to grace?

Alan

Comment: I think you need to provide more detail on how you are 'recording' the contributions

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how your organisation works and how strict the rules are. One could argue that all memberships are renewed at the end of the year and payments are created but with status pending. A member could still benefit altough they did not pay. This means that the membership status should stay active,

One could also argue that as long as someone did not paid the member has no benefit in that case you want an inactive status come into play.

What is really cool about CiviCRM is that it is possible to define those membership status rules yourself. You can do that under Administer --> CiviMember --> Membership status rules.

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha - I solved my own issue ....

It was related to some code I put together myself and forgot, that checks to see if a grace member has had a contribution and re-instates membership.

This was related to some other code that I found a couple of years ago that handled the 'joining' of memberships when contributions have been bulk loaded ( which doesn't auto link ) from this post  https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=19322.0  - but the code had started failing due to deprecated mysql code ...  fixed now

Comment: Ah we have all had the same thing.... ;-)